# How to formulate multiple unsubscribe functions from firebase in a redux app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

in a react-native redux app, I want to unsubscribe from multiple onSnapshot listeners (5), when the user logs out. Ive attempted to unsubscribe from my multiple listeners but it continues to error after the logout process with:

[image]

Here is my logout action:

```
export const logoutUser = (uid, role) => {

    return (dispatch) => {
        onProfileChange(uid, true);
        getConversations(uid, true);
        getAgenda(uid, role, true)
        onAccountChange(uid, true)

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            firebase
                .auth()
                .signOut()
                .then(() => {
                    dispatch({ type: types.RESET_APP });
                    console.log('Dispatching types.RESET_APP');
                    resolve();
                })
                .catch((error) => reject(error.message));
        });
    };
};
```

Here is `onProfileChange` action (structure of this action is similar to the rest, with conditional statement for unsubscribe argument). this is obviously located in an external file an imported into the component and mapped to props

```
export const onProfileChange = (uid, isUnsubscribe) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        const unsubscribe = firebase.firestore().collection('profiles').doc(uid).onSnapshot((doc) => {
            console.log('Profile: ' + JSON.stringify(doc.data()));
            dispatch({ type: types.LOAD_PROFILE, payload: doc.data() });
        });
        if ( typeof isUnsubscribe != "undefined" || isUnsubscribe == true) {
            unsubscribe()
        } 
    };
};
```

In my component's constructor, I invoke the function above like so:

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    props.onAccountChange(props.authUser.uid);
}
```

then this function inside the same component is executed on a button press:

```
logout = () => {
        this.props
            .logoutUser(this.props.authUser.uid, this.props.role)
            .then(() => {
                this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
            })
            .catch((err) => alert(err));
    };
```

EDIT: 
Firebase rule set:

```
service cloud.firestore {

  // allow only authenticated users to view database data
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    allow read: if request.auth.uid != null
  }

  // allow only the logged in user to write their own documents
  // i.e Account data, Profile data, Messages, User-Conversations
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{uid} {
      allow read, write, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == uid
    }
    match/users/{uid} {
      allow update: if request.auth.uid != null 
    }
    match /profiles/{uid} {
        allow write, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == uid
    }

    // allow reading of all profile data if authenticated
    match /profiles/{uid} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null
    }
    match /users/{uid} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null
    }
    match /mostWanted/{docId} {
      allow read, update, create: if request.auth.uid != null
    }

    // Get multiple Docs by single owner (User-Conversations)
    match /user-conversations/{docId} {
      allow read, delete:
        if resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid
    }
    // Do the same ^ for /messages/{docId}
    // => requires 'receiver' data property to integrate
    match /messages/{docId} {
      allow create, read, update: if request.auth.uid != null
    }
    // allow read/write of user-convo's if authenticated
    match /user-conversations/{docId} {
      allow read, write, update: if request.auth.uid != null
    }    
  }
}
```

Why am I still getting this `firebase/permission-denied` error if the listeners have been unsubscribed? The only other thing im thinking of is to set an auth state listener in all these actions. and when it changes call the `unSubscribe` reference

Comment: Can you see if your security rules on Firestore are set correctly?

Comment: I've edited the post with current firebase rule set. but if the listeners are unsubscribed *before* being signed out, why would auth state matter? @BenButterworth

Comment: I can't see where you actually call the `onSnapshot` initially, I guess that's somewhere else in the code? I don't fully understand `onProfileChange`, why do you call `onSnapshot` and immediately unsubscribe? I would assume you need to use the same reference you created in the first few `onSnapshot`(call in code youre not showing?), because now you're just creating new ones and stopping those.

Comment: What I mean is, your `unsubscribe` variable has to have the reference to the original listeners you created.

Comment: how is the reference not in `unsubscribe`? the firebase function is assigned to the variable, and based on the invocation of the redux action (if `isUnsubscribe` is true) then the reference variable is conditionally invoked? is this not what is supposed to be done @BenButterworth

Comment: @BenButterworth the call to `onSnapshot` is clearly inside the `onProfileChange` action, maybe you missed it. are you saying I need to store a reference to the action itself?

Comment: @jim have you solve it ? if no, can you provide a working code ? (also calling unsubscribe just after onSnapshot is useless)

Comment: @CR7 how do you call the reference to the firestore onSnapshot, from *outside* of the redux action? the only other way i can think of to work this is to not  dispatch an action from another file. the code ive provided is the code from my project. `logoutUser()` is a component function, and `onProfileChange()` is in an external file

Comment: An idea: When you create your snapshot listener (you haven't shown us that code), return the handler the `unsubscribe`. Then, when you're done, call that function.

Comment: @BenB **please** read the `onProfileChange()` function. the listener is in there plain as day => `const unsubscribe = firebase.firestore().collection('profiles').doc(uid).onSnapshot((doc) => { ....`

Comment: I thought you only used that to unsubscribe. That clearly won't work the way you're doing it. Like I said before, you need to use the same reference that you subscribed with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple attempts at this, ive been able to circumvent the error, although im not thrilled with the way its done, because it's seemingly polluting the component. Anyway, here is how I did it for anyone looking to add and detach firestore snapshot listeners in react-native projects.

I have my drawer component which sets the listener in its constructor:

```
imports {...}

class DrawerContentComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);

        this.unsubscribeAccount = firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(props.authUser.uid).onSnapshot((doc) => {
            console.log("EXECUTING ONSNAPSHOT()...")
            if (doc.get('role') == 'Influencer') {
                onProfileChange(props.authUser.uid);
            }
        });
    }

    logout = () => {
        this.props
            .logoutUser()
            .then(() => {
                this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
            })
            .catch((err) => alert(err));
    };

    // CALL REFERENCE TO LISTENER ON UNMOUNT
    componentWillUnmount() {
        console.log("EXECUTING COMPONENT WILL UNMOUNT")
        this.unsubscribeAccount();
    }

    < rest of component >
}
```

the action executed in the logout component function:

```
export const logoutUser = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            firebase
                .auth()
                .signOut()
                .then(() => {
                    dispatch({ type: types.RESET_APP });
                    console.log('Dispatching types.RESET_APP');
                    resolve();
                })
                .catch((error) => reject(error.message));
        });
    };
};
```

Initially what I wanted was a way to call one action (`logoutUser()`) and have that unsubscribe all the listeners, as originally, I had all the listeners set in my one of my actions files. this was not working no matter I stubbornly tried.

But what im still curious about, is the reason behind why this actually worked in eradicating the `permission-denied` error. By my logic, the execution order is:

1. button is pressed
2. component's `logout()` function is entered
3. it invokes the action `logoutUser()`
4. switch navigator changes back from the drawer navigator and the drawer component is unmounted
5. the reference to `this.unsubscribeAccount()` is reached.

This doesn't make sense to me because the signOut() firebase auth action is *still* happening before the unsubscribe, so it makes sense that temporarily, the listener is still attached at the point auth state changes. and I confirmed that is the case. the listener reference is the last thing to execute.

Comment: I'm not sure, but `permission-denied` might be caused because when you call `onProfileChange` when you want to logout, you inadvertently try to resubscribe to the same document. You could test this, but just duplicating the subscribe code and seeing that the 2nd line causes the error.

Comment: I don't think its got anything to do with the firebase signOut() function, because it doesn't even happen. You could test **this** by logging something in the `signOut()` `.then` callback.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is what I meant, when I said "your unsubscribe variable has to have the reference to the original listeners you created." You cannot just create a new subscription when you log out, and then immediately unsubscribe from that. That won't do anything to the old ones you opened previously.

Just pass the unsubscribe action to the action creator? In your logoutButtonHandler, call `this.props.logoutUser(unsubscribeAccount)`. If you have more, you could put them in an array, and pass the array into logOutuser, and in there, you can just map over the array, call each element (unsubscribe functions) of the array.

```
export const logoutUser = (unsubscribeAccount) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            unsubscribeAccount();
            firebase
                .auth()
                .signOut()
                .then(() => {
                    dispatch({ type: types.RESET_APP });
                    console.log('Dispatching types.RESET_APP');
                    resolve();
                })
                .catch((error) => reject(error.message));
        });
    };
};
```